# Change the destination remote branch name within a Git pre-push hook

Tags: git

I've been trying to make a pre-push hook that would read in the remote ref from STDIN, modify it, and have Git accept the set of revisions being pushed and create the remote ref with the modified name. For example, what I want to do is,

1. let's say the client does a `git push origin foo`,
2. the pre-push hook would intercept that and change the refspec from `foo` to `refs/heads/foo:refs/heads/foobar`,
3. the revisions included in the push are accepted, and
4. Git would create a branch called `foobar` on the remote repo (as opposed to `foo`).

Is this approach possible? If so, how can I modify the client's branch argument within the hook and have it redirect to a different branch name? Let me know if I can add in any information. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that in a pre-push hook, it's far too late: at this point git has connected to the remote and given it the ref-names that it (your git) intends to give to it (the remote git) to update, and translated those names to SHA-1s (the remote git does this translation and your local git just saves the results and then passes them on to your hook).  Your local git is going to proceed forwards, if you allow it, with those names.

What you can do, though I would advise against as it's overly complicated and hence likely to break, is have your pre-push hook reject particular pushes, but *also* (first) run its own *new* `git push` with some other name(s) and, if needed, something that causes your pre-push hook not to do all this yet again.

For instance, consider the following pseudo-code (Python and shell arbitrarily mixed):

```
if ${PUSH_HOOK_RUNNING:-false}; then exit 0; fi # don't recurse

accepted=[]
replaced=[]
while read line; do
    lref, lsha1, rref, rsha1 = line.split()
    if lref == "refs/heads/foo" && rref == "refs/heads/foo"; then
        replaced.append("refs/heads/foo:refs/heads/foobar")
    else
        accepted.append("$lref:$rref")
    fi
done
if empty(replaced); then
    exit 0 # let this git push run
else
    # run a substitute git push as part of the hook
    PUSH_HOOK_RUNNING=true git push $accepted $replaced
    exit 1 # prevent this git push entirely
fi
```

The above has numerous flaws and exposes a bunch of races that can be fixed by examining the local and remote reference names and SHA-1s.  (In particular, consider what happens if the local name `xyz` refers to commit `df08eb357dd7f432c3dcbe0ef4b3212a38b4aeff` initially, but by the time the "inner" `git push` is invoked, it refers to some other SHA-1 entirely due to a separate process doing `git update-ref` or `git branch -m` or whatever.)

---

All that said, a much simpler way to deal with this is to have your own front-end command that you use *instead of* `git push`, that inserts whatever transformations and checks you would like to have happen, and then runs `git push` for you.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I ran into the same sort of workarounds/solutions as well. The first solution regarding calling another git push inside the hook would result in an error message on the client's shell. I tried redirecting this error message to the null device, but it doesn't seem possible. The second solution i.e. wrapper over git push, seems to be the way to go although it's somewhat choppy in the sense that with the use of other git commands, this would be the one "special condition".